# AWS - RedShift CloudFormation with Defer Maintenance enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to find how to set `Defer maintenance window` to `Enabled` using CloudFormation configuration.  Currently when I create the cluster using CF this option is set to disabled, and I can't find a property to enable this.

Is there a property to enable the `Defer maintenance window` option?

I know I can do it from the CLI, using something like:

```
response = client.modify_cluster_maintenance(
    ClusterIdentifier='string',
    DeferMaintenance=True|False,
    DeferMaintenanceIdentifier='string',
    DeferMaintenanceStartTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    DeferMaintenanceEndTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    DeferMaintenanceDuration=123
)
```

but I'm looking for a way to set this using CloudFormation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that isn't possible.

The only maintenance-related value supported by CloudFormation is `PreferredMaintenanceWindow`.

Worst-case, you could create an [AWS Lambda-backed custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) that can run the `modify_cluster_maintenance()` command once the cluster has been created. (Writing Custom Resources is a bit tricky, especially if you've never used Lambda previously.)